# Fastify addSchema to provide meaningful name of the OpenAPI 2.0 definition objects

Tags: openapi, fastify

I have some schema definitions created with fastify as in below, where I have used 'title' to give meaningful name of my models.

```js
fastify.addSchema({
        $id: 'persistence-query-params',
        title: "PersistenceQueryParams",   // Here
        type: 'object',
        description: 'Persistence Service GET API URL query specification. Applicable for GET API only.',
        properties: {
               ...........
        },
    });
```

However when I am looking at the json generated from the swagger (I am using fastify-swagger: 4.8.4 and fastify: 3.20.1), I am seeing this

```yaml
  def-7:                    ## Here
    title: PersistenceQueryParams
    type: object
    description: >-
      Persistence Service GET API URL query specification. Applicable for GET
      API only.
    properties:
```

This is coming up in the OpenAPI 2.0 https://editor.swagger.io/, when loading the json generated out of that schema.

I have tried out adding the name field also:

```
name: "PersistenceQueryParams",
```

However no luck.

How can I create meaningful names, instead of def-0, def-1 etc in OpenAPI 2.0?

Thanks,
Pradip

Comment: There is an [open issue for that](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger/issues/286). Anyway, the `$id` will be the right field to change it

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reading this now it is now possible to do this. You need to override the `refResolver` in the config like this:

```js
fastify.register(swagger, {
    refResolver: {
      buildLocalReference(json, baseUri, fragment, i) {
        // This mirrors the default behaviour
        // see: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger/blob/1b53e376b4b752481643cf5a5655c284684383c3/lib/mode/dynamic.js#L17
        if (!json.title && json.$id) {
          json.title = json.$id;
        }
        // Fallback if no $id is present
        if (!json.$id) {
          return `def-${i}`;
        }

        return `${json.$id}`;
      },
    },
    openapi: {
      // Your spec here...
    }
  });
```

Clickable comment link:

https://github.com/fastify/fastify-swagger/blob/1b53e376b4b752481643cf5a5655c284684383c3/lib/mode/dynamic.js#L17

Now you're refs will have meaningful names.